# Amalfi coast by motor bike?

Tags: italy, sorrento

Me and my friend were planning to visit Amalfi. I was wondering if is it a good idea to see other places on the coast line through a motor bike. Also, if not then what is the best way to visit other places like Sorrento, Positano etc. ?

Comment: Depends what you means by best. There are buses along the coast.